# Soldering in marine environment: how to prevent future corrosion

Tags: soldering, corrosion

I regularly need to connect cables on boats. One of the best ways to make these connections reliable is soldering. Usually this involves soldering to a cable with a heavy layer of verdigris. Resin based flux is usually not enough to remove the oxidation from these cables. Also sea water will have soaked up into the cable. Thus it is common that the whole lenght of the cable surface is corroded; so cutting off the end to find uncorroded copper isn't feasible.

Currently I use hydrochloric acid to strip the oxidation of the cable and then rosin cored 60/40 solder which works very well. However the residue of the hydrochloric acid encourages future corrosion what I would like to avoid / minimize.

What are better ways to prepare such cables for soldering?

Comment: For really corroded copper a solution/ paste of sal ammoniac (ammonium chloride) works wonders. Nasty fumes though (HCl and ammonia) as the heat breaks it down.

Comment: neutralize and wash of the hcl,though it would be better to think of a way to not have them corrode in the first place, this is just trouble waiting for you.

Comment: @PlasmaHH that's pretty much impossible in a marine environment. The salty moisture is in the air.. You can only slow it down but you can't stop it, and once it gets in...

Comment: not sure about marine environment, but I was able to clean heavy oxide from a earth copper braid that had been in the ground for years by using simply a mixture of vinegar and baking soda (in equal parts in volume IIRC). Scrubbing with a toothbrush made the copper shiny again.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Neutralizing/washing with a sodium hydroxide solution is definitely an option I will consider, as NaCl will be present anyway, having this residue won't make much of a difference I would think. Working with corroded cables is just a fact I have to deal with all the time. There is no point worrying about what someone else should have done differently years ago.

Comment: @JImDearden Ammonium chloride is not recommended for electrical installations either. Is there actually an advantage over HCl? Is the residue easier to remove?

Comment: Its not something I would normally think of using in electrical installations, its more a plumber's thing but very good if you want to tin the bit of a highly messed up soldering iron. Its highly soluble and slightly acidic in solution so in its native (unheated) form it isn't a strong acid like HCl.  Here's a few recipes  http://chestofbooks.com/reference/Henley-s-20th-Century-Formulas-Recipes-Processes-Vol3/Fluxes-For-Soldering.html